# How to read the first line in github commit?

Tags: git, github

I've been working with github for a couple of weeks now. Using my version control for my homework since I now work on campus with a laptop and at home with my desktop.

Below is a picture of one of the commits for reference.
[image: One commit]

And here is another just for comparison.
[image: Another]

This is probably a dumb question but I've been googling for about 12mins trying to get some sort of definition to what the `@@-5,3 +5,18@@` & `@@-12,22 +12,51@@` actually mean.

I feel like it has to do with number of lines. But I haven't found anything that directly explains what it is.

Can anyone explain? Or maybe point me to a refference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the *unified* diff (also called `unidiff`) format.  You can interpret `@@ -A,B +C,D @@` as:

- At line number A in the first file, for a bloc of B lines,
- at line number C in the second file, for a bloc of D lines

...then...

- the lines starting with  (space) are common to both files,
- the lines starting with `-` are only in the first file,
- and the lines starting with `+`  are only in the second file.